# Finding unique set of values across columns [SQL]

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, row

Do you know if there is any smart way to identify unique set of values across a number of columns in SQL?

Example, input:

```
col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
A     A     A     A
A     B     A     A
A     B     C     D
D     C     B     A
```

Desired output:

```
col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4  col_output
A     A     A     A      'A'
A     B     A     A      'A','B' 
A     B     C     D      'A','B','C','D'
D     C     B     D      'B','C','D'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Spark SQL. Tag added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a giant `case` expression.  Using standard syntax:

```
select t.*,
       ('''' || col_1 || ''';' ||
        (case when col2 not in (col1) then '''' || col_2 || ''';' else '' end) ||
        (case when col3 not in (col1, col2) then '''' || col_3 || ''';' else '' end) ||
        (case when col4 not in (col1, col2, col3) then '''' || col_4 || ''';' else '' end)
       ) as col_output
from t;
```

This actually leaves a semicolon at the end.  It is not hard to get rid of this, but the best method depends on the database.

Comment: Is `giant` a reserved ANSI SQL keyword? :P

Answer (score 2):

Try using UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dropDuplicates = udf((arr: Seq[String]) => {arr.map(x => "'"+ x +"'").distinct.mkString(",")})

df.withColumn("col_output",dropDuplicates(array("col_1", "col_2", "col_3","col_4"))).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_output     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
|A    |A    |A    |A    |'A'            |
|A    |B    |A    |A    |'A','B'        |
|A    |B    |C    |D    |'A','B','C','D'|
|D    |C    |B    |D    |'D','C','B'    |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
```